# Will Spring transaction REQUIRES_NEW be propagated to the methods within the method?

Tags: java, spring, transactional, propagation

My requirement is to commit/rollback changes from `method2` and not be dependent on the outer transaction. So I used `REQUIRES_NEW` to commit the inner transaction.
But I need some clarification as to the type of propagation the other methods will hold when called from the method.

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public String method1(long id) {
    ABC obj = method2(id);
    method3(obj);
    myDAO.saveOrUpdate(obj);
}

private ABC method2(long id) {
    ABC obj1 = myDAO.readData(id);
    ...
    ...
    return obj1;
}

private void method3(ABC obj) {
    ABC obj1 = (ABC)obj.clone();
    obj1.setId(123);
    obj1.setName("Name");
    myDAO.persist(obj1);
}
```

Now the issue is the data is not committed in `method3` and `method1`, even after setting the propagation as `REQUIRES_NEW`. Or can we have this propagation only in DAO layer?

Comment: From javadocs: `Actual transaction suspension will not work out-of-the-box on all transaction managers. This in particular applies to {@link org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager},  which requires the {@code javax.transaction.TransactionManager} to be made available it to it (which is server-specific in standard Java EE).
@see org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager#setTransactionManager` What app server, database and transaction manager do you use?

Comment: What is your current flush mode? Add a call to flush flush after after saveOrUpdate in method1.

Comment: Thanks for the information Vladimir. I am using hibernate and database is Oracle.

Comment: @rbento, I have tried using flush after saveOrUpdate, but it doesn't commit the changes. The database is synchronized for the outer transaction. I guess since the saveOrUpdate in dao layer is again another method (which implements a genericDao), and as Vladimir said that transaction suspension doesn't work out-of-box, that's why the transaction doesn't get committed even in method1.

Comment: Why should it commit after each method? The transaction is started at the moment method1 starts (it suspends a current transaction) and will be committed at the end of method1. As method2 and method3 are internal method calls marking them `@Transactional` is useless (Spring AOP by default uses proxies and internal method calls don't pass through the proxy).

Comment: It shouldn't commit after each method, but I wanted the commit to happen after method1 for both the transactions. But its simply not happening. Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

As i see in your code the method2(..) belong to same object calling method1(..) and that cause the method2() to use the same new transaction created by method1, this behaviour is forced by the proxy mode spring use i quote:

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation, in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object, will not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional

To make two transactions you must create the second method in another object and annotated with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`
to have the desired effect